# Verify mobile app Google

Tags: ios, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I've added `kGTLRAuthScopeDrive` scope to `OIDAuthorizationRequest` and I am facing the issue shown in the picture below:
[image]

How can I verify my ios app?

Answer (score 0):

[OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)

> Starting July 18, 2017, Google OAuth clients that request certain sensitive OAuth scopes will be subject to review by Google.
>
> Add-ons, web apps, and other deployments (such as apps that use the Apps Script API) may need verification.

You must apply to have your application verified by google before others will be able to use it.   [Verify](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#steps)

By clicking advanced you should be able to login yourself as the developer who created it.  this is used for testing only